# Maquina virtual criada em computador X não funciona com computador Y

Tags: vmware

Eu criei uma maquina virtual em um notebook X do Ubuntu 12.04, no qual funcionou normalmente. Criei essa maquina para que eu pudesse utilizar um banco de dados do MySQL e transitar entre dois computadores sem tem que reconfigurar o banco de dados. Porem, quando eu liguei a maquina virtual no notebook Y, apareceu isso:

[image: Ooops.]

Ignorei o aviso e liguei a maquina. No notebook Y ela fica extremamente lerda e quase inutilizável, o que não acontece no notebook X.

O notebook X possui um Intel i5 (Sandy Bridge), com 6GB de RAM e uma Intel HD 3000. O notebook Y possui um AMD Dual-Core E1-2500, com 4GB de RAM e uma AMD Radeon HD 8248. Ambos rodam Windows 8.1.

É impossível que eu faça uma mesma maquina virtual funcionar nesses dois computadores? O notebook Y não é capaz de rodar maquinas virtuais?

Comment: Quantos GB de RAM você alocou para a máquina virtual? Se foi 2GB ou mais, faz uma grande diferença o hospedeiro ter 4 ou 6GB...

Comment: @epx a maquina virtual tem o padrão que o vmware aloca pro Ubuntu, que é 1GB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notei que o sistema convidado (*guest*) é 64 bits. Já passei por duas situações semelhantes por causa dessa questão.

Primeiro, certifique-se de que os dois sistemas hospedeiros (*hosts*) são 64 bits. Existem algumas limitações ao emular um SO 64 sobre um 32 bits. O VirtualBox, por exemplo, nem inicia a execução.

Segundo, certifique-se de que o hardware está configurado (BIOS) para suportar virtualização nativamente. Em algumas placas, isso vem desabilitado por padrão. A opção deve se chamar VT (Virtualization Technology) ou algo parecido. [Este link](http://h30499.www3.hp.com/t5/Windows-Server-2003-for-64-Bit/How-to-enable-VT-in-BIOS-for-64bit-support-in-vmware-HP-DC7700/td-p/5041647#.UxnbWD9dV2k) talvez ajude a encontrar a opção. Com a opção desativada, o VMWare tentará simular a virtualização via software, o que é muito mais lento.

Se não for nada disso, pode ser que simplesmente por causa do estado armazenado da VM. Seria como você hibernar um SO, colocar o HD em outra PC diferente e então ligá-lo. O hardware mudou, mas os drivers permanecem os antigos. Se você reiniciar a mesma o problema continua?

Comment: Sim, ambos os hosts são 64 bits. 
Mas se for a questão da BIOS, o VMWare não daria um aviso mais especifico? Se for caso, acho estranho ter dado um aviso vago como aquele.

Comment: @athosbr99 Não conheço em detalhes as mensagens de erro, mas veja que adicionei mais um parágrafo na minha resposta. O problema pode ser simplesmente porque trocou de hardware sem desligar a imagem.

Answer (score 0):

O Virtualbox (da Oracle) https://www.virtualbox.org/ funciona no MAC, Windows e Linux e você pode usá-lo com máquinas virtuais criadas pelo VMWare. Eu uso com sucesso no Windows para abrir e executar maquinas virtuais criadas pelo VMWare no MAC OS X. O Virtual Box é capaz de reconhecer o HD criado no VMWare e faz o boot normalmente. Você deverá reconfigurar no VirtualBox do seu Notebook Windows os dispositivos de rede compatibilizando o ambiente, além de alocar a quantidade de memória adequada.